# how to find if a field contains a string in a field from mongoDB

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb

I have a problem that I can get a data from mongoDB but it's not what i want.

I just want to get a data, if datas have "#l" sting in the message field, I want it.

here's data on mongodb

```
({...someData, message: 'asdfff #lol blah blah blah hellohellohellohello'})
({...someData, message: '#lol asdfff blah blah blah byebyebye'})
({...someData, message: 'asdfff asdffasfdah blah blah #lol hello'})
({...someData, message: 'asdfff #l blah blah blah hello'})
({...someData, message: 'asdfff #lo blah blah blah hello'})
```

here's what i've done

```
const hashtagPosts = await Post.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          message: { $regex: `#${hashtag}` },
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: {
          createdAt: -1,
        },
      },
      {
        $limit: 10,
      },
    ]);
```

```
    const hashtagPosts = await Post.find({
      message: { $regex: `#${hashtag}` },
    });
```

and If I run these code with "#l" this hashtag I will get this data

```
({...someData, message: 'asdfff #lol blah blah blah hellohellohellohello'})
({...someData, message: '#lol asdfff blah blah blah byebyebye'})
({...someData, message: 'asdfff asdffasfdah blah blah #lol hello'})
({...someData, message: 'asdfff #l blah blah blah hello'})
({...someData, message: 'asdfff #lo blah blah blah hello'})
```

What I want, the result

```
({...someData, message: 'asdfff #l blah blah blah hello'})
```

if I search with "#l" this searchword I want to get datas that contain exact the same searchword
like "#l" => "#l"

not contain "#lol" "#lo"
is it possible?
I have no idea how can i get datas like that. thanks for reading my question.

Comment: You're executing a RegEx query, so RegEx rules apply. You want `\b` for word boundary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your regex, if you want to allow any match precending `#l` except a letter you could use the negative lookahead syntax like [this](https://regex101.com/r/SDOUuO/1):

```
message: { $regex: `#l(?![a-zA-Z])` },
```

And you can add any "illegal" characther to the group.

If all you want is exact match for `#l` it's much easier, we either allow a space or end of string, like [this](https://regex101.com/r/43kPYS/1):

```
message: { $regex: `#l($|\s)` },
```

(I didn't deal with the precending edge case under the assumption no string will be like `#hashtag#l`, but using the same technique you an ensure the tokens you want before it are there.

Answer (score -1):

[MongoDB Playground with example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6jpEnKTtio0)
Above answer explanation is correct.

DB Record:

```
   [
  {
    "key": 1,
    "message": "asdfff #lol blah blah blah hellohellohellohello",
    
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "message": "#lol asdfff blah blah blah byebyebye"
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "message": "asdfff asdffasfdah blah blah #lol hello"
  },
  {
    "key": 4,
    "message": "asdfff #l blah blah blah hello"
  },
  {
    "key": 5,
    "message": "asdfff #lo blah blah blah hello"
  }
]
```

Aggregation Query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "message": {
        // put your query in $regex option
        $regex: "#l(?![a-zA-Z])",
        
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Output Screenshoot:
[image: Output]

Comment: Negative lookahead is not the way. OP explicitly mentions they want only "#l". What if the text contains "#1", or "#l,", or ends with "#l"?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this way.

```
const hashtagPosts = await Post.find({
      message: /#l/i
    });
```

Another way to do this.

```
const hashtagPosts = await Post.find({
      message:  { "$regex": "#l", "$options": "i" }
    });
```